# How to refactor components with almost the same JSX structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of components which have almost identical JSX structure. These components are `Panel`, `SidePanel`, `Card` and `Modal`.

The only differences are the `className` because I am using `BEM` naming convention for CSS class name, and the event handler function and where and how the event handler function gets triggered.

How should I refactor these components in order to prevent using duplicated JSX all over the place?

Below are two example from my Panel and SidePanel component JSX,

```
  <div>
    <article
      className={classes}
      id={this.props.id}
      style={this.props.style}
    >
      {title && (
        <div className="panel__title">
          <h3>{title}</h3>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="panel__content">{this.props.children}</div>
      {toolbarButtons && (
        <footer className="panel__footer">{toolbarButtons}</footer>
      )}
    </article>
  </div>
```

SidePanel,

```
  <div>
    <article className={classes} id={id} style={style}>
      {title && (
        <div className="side-panel__title">
          <h3>{title}</h3>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="side-panel__content">{children}</div>
      {toolbarButtons && (
        <footer className="side-panel__footer">{toolbarButtons}</footer>
      )}
    </article>
  </div>
```

And you can already see the similarity between these two components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is pass the css prefix as a prop.

You can use the following `basePanel`:

```
  const basePanel = (props) => (<div>
    <article className={props.classes} id={props.id} style={props.style}>
      {title && (
        <div className={`${props.cssPrefix}__title`}>
          <h3>{props.title}</h3>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className={`${props.cssPrefix}__content`}>{props.children}</div>
      {toolbarButtons && (
        <footer className={`${props.cssPrefix}__footer`}>{props.toolbarButtons}</footer>
      )}
    </article>
  </div>);
```

Then use it like :

Your Panel becomes:

```
const Panel = (props) => <BasePanel {...props} cssPrefix="panel" />;
```

Your side Panel becomes:

```
const SidePanel = (props) => <BasePanel {...props} cssPrefix="side-panel" />;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am doing right now, however, the complicated part is different event handling logic for these components.

Comment: where are the events handlers ? It does not show in your code

Comment: it is added via `document.addEventListener` at the time component get mounted

Comment: Why don't you just pass it as props as well ?

Comment: Because these events need to be captured when clicking outside the component

Comment: Can you add the code to you post ? I will update my answer